# RecyclerView only display the first item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to get data from a SQLite Database , and display it on a RecyclerView . However , the adapter only displays the first item . Many related topics are talking about changing the height of the parent layout to xxdp or to wrap_content , which I tried . Here is the code :

QuoteAdapter.java:

```
public class QuoteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QuoteAdapter.QuoteViewHolder> {

private QuoteItemBinding binding;
private Context mContext;
private Cursor mCursor;

public QuoteAdapter(Context context,Cursor cursor) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mCursor = cursor;



}


@Override
public QuoteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(
            (Activity)mContext, R.layout.quote_item);

    int quoteLayoutId = R.layout.quote_item;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;

    View view = inflater.inflate(quoteLayoutId,parent,shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
    QuoteViewHolder quoteViewHolder = new QuoteViewHolder(view);
     return quoteViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(QuoteViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if(!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
        return;
    }

    String category = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(QuoteContract.QuoteEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORY));
    String author = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(QuoteContract.QuoteEntry.COLUMN_AUTHOR));
    String quote = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(QuoteContract.QuoteEntry.COLUMN_CONTENT));
    Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),quote);

    holder.mQuoteAuthor.setText(author);
    holder.mQuoteCategory.setText(category);
    holder.mQuoteTextView.setText(quote);

    //Passer l'ID en tag du itemView avec  holder.itemView.setTag(id) si on veut une action paritculiere sur un item
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mCursor.getCount();
}

public void swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
    if(mCursor != null) mCursor.close();
    mCursor = newCursor;
    if(newCursor != null) {
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

public class QuoteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView mQuoteTextView;
    public TextView mQuoteAuthor;
    public TextView mQuoteCategory;


    public QuoteViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mQuoteTextView = binding.quote;
        mQuoteAuthor = binding.quoteAuthor;
        mQuoteCategory = binding.quoteCategory;
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }



}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private QuoteAdapter mQuoteAdapter;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private ActivityMainBinding mainBinding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);
    RecyclerView quoteListRecycler = mainBinding.recyclerMain;

    quoteListRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    QuoteDbHelper dbHelper = new QuoteDbHelper(this);

    mDb = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = getAllQuotes();

    mQuoteAdapter = new QuoteAdapter(this,cursor);

    quoteListRecycler.setAdapter(mQuoteAdapter);



}
private Cursor getAllQuotes() {
   return mDb.query(QuoteContract.QuoteEntry.TABLE_NAME,
           null,
           null,
           null,
           null,
           null,
           QuoteContract.QuoteEntry.COLUMN_DATE);
}
}
```

quote_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/quote_item_padding"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/quote_item_padding"
android:id="@+id/item_for_recycler"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="56dp">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/quoteCategory"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/quote_item_padding"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/quote_item_padding"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    tools:text="Category : Business"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/quote"
    tools:text="Hello there"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/quoteAuthor"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/quote_item_padding"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/quote_item_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/quote_item_padding"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    tools:text="Leonardo DeMontesquieu"
    />

</FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: when you mean, the adapter only displays the first item, does it means that you scroll down to other items?

Comment: When i try it with the simplest layout i got to show more than 1 item with parent and child view wrapping

try instead of having all the attribute in those textview, try with the simplest layout. just 3 normal wrapped textview with default or at least 10sp font size. parent layout height should also be wrap_content.

also make sure the android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView from base layout has enough height to show more than 1 item

Comment: I still cannot get it to work... The thing is that it displays only the last item issued from my SQLite database ,the first item that have been retrieved with by the query . I can't even scroll , i tried wrapping the recyclerview inside of a scrollView , and still not working .

Comment: And I also tried to put a ClickListener in the view holder , on the item , showing a Toast on click , but it doesn't show anything , maybe it's related ?

Comment: just want to make sure to remove some doubts, did you debug and place the break point in Cursor cursor = getAllQuotes();? did the cursor.getCount(); returns value more than 1?

Comment: It returns a value of 3 , which is the number of entries i have in my database

Comment: hmm very weird, because mine just shows all items (item layout is wrap content including parent). only different is i also declare:
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
try adding the layoutmanager as well. Also I noticed you used DataBindingUtil and not the manual way of findViewByID(R.....), maybe try instead of DataBindingUtil, try using findviewByid, maybe the problem is caused by the DataBindingUtil